# Running time in Ocaml

Tags: time, ocaml

How to figure out the amount of time my code has taken in ocaml? are there any functions to measure that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to measure execution time of individual functions, this utility function is helpful in many cases:

```
let time f x =
    let t = Sys.time() in
    let fx = f x in
    Printf.printf "Execution time: %fs\n" (Sys.time() -. t);
    fx
```

where `f` is any function which takes `x` as the argument and returns something.

Answer (score 18):

In my own coding, I use `Unix.gettimeofday ()`, which returns a float value with a resolution of much less than one second.  It's described in the [documentation for the OCaml Unix module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html).  Despite the name of the module, this function also works in Windows (and probably in almost all environments you might encounter).

If I rewrite pad's answer I get the following code:

```
let time f x =
    let start = Unix.gettimeofday ()
    in let res = f x
    in let stop = Unix.gettimeofday ()
    in let () = Printf.printf "Execution time: %fs\n%!" (stop -. start)
    in
       res
```

Comment: I get "Error: Reference to undefined global `Unix'" on windows.

Comment: There is a `Unix` module on Windows that supports large parts of the same interface as on Unix and Linux. `gettimeofday` is supported. See https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.06/libunix.html. I can't help with your specific problem, I'm not a Windows user.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Sys.time(). It returns the processor time, in seconds, used by the program since the beginning of execution.

Source : http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Sys.html

Comment: Sys.time() is giving incorrect running. It gave 341.1 s for a small program. When I used unix time command, it gave only 0.001 s.

Comment: I've never seen a failure like this.  Can you show what your code looks like?  (Maybe add it at the end of your question.)

Comment: Calling Sys.time() in a Toplevel will return the amount of time the Toplevel thread has spent running code.

Comment: Good idea, but 341 s is a lot of computing to do at toplevel (?).