# OCaml: measure execution time in toplevel

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-toplevel

How should we measure the execution time of a function in the OCaml toplevel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running time in Ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061421/running-time-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @user3075773 says, you can use `Sys.time`. However note that it returns processor time (CPU time). More often I want to know the wall clock time (elapsed time). You can get this from `Unix.gettimeofday`:

```
let time f x =
    let t = Unix.gettimeofday () in
    let fx = f x in
    Printf.printf "execution elapsed time: %f sec\n"
        (Unix.gettimeofday () -. t);
    fx
```

Comment: This is a crucial distinction.  Thanks for highlighting it.  One might want either kind of time, but you definitely don't want to mix them up if they differ.

Answer (score 8):

```
let time f x =
    let t = Sys.time() in
    let fx = f x in
    Printf.printf "execution time: %fs\n" (Sys.time() -. t);
    fx
```

Works with any function, it will print how long did the function take to run in the toplevel.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gettimeofday` like the accepted answer suggests is not a good idea as it is sensitive to calendar time operating system adjustements (e.g. via `ntp`).

If you just want CPU time then using `Sys.time` is fine. If you want wall-clock time, then a monotonic time source should be used. One is available for OCaml in the [mtime](http://erratique.ch/software/mtime) package.